# Google scripts fetching from GmailApp problem

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail

I really need your help with a simple function that is not working for me,
I am trying to fetch all the emails in my inbox under a specific label,
As I am doing it, It is fetching every mail about 10 times as duplications,
(I have 120 emails in all Gmail, It fetched 800+ mails)

I checked it multiple times and I don't get the problem.

Hopefully, you will see it
Thank you in advance!

```
function getGmailEmails(){
  var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("ToBeProcessedByGAS");
  var threads = label.getThreads();

  for(var i = threads.length - 1; i>=0; i--){
    var messages = threads[i].getMessages();

    for(var j = 0; j <messages.length; j++){
      var message = messages[j];
      extractDetails(message);
      GmailApp.markMessageRead(message);
    }
    threads[i].removeLabel(label);

  }
}

function extractDetails(message){
  var dateTime = message.getDate();
  var subjectText = message.getSubject();
  var senderDetails = message.getFrom();
  var bodyContents = message.getPlainBody();

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Mails")
  //var activesheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().sheet;
  sheet.appendRow([dateTime,senderDetails,subjectText,bodyContents]);
}
```

Comment: I ran your code and do not get duplicates. Are you sure you didn't run it more than once?

Comment: I'm 100% sure :)

Comment: Does this happen to different labels too?